# Fitting one dataset as a function of other datasets in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting, deconvolution

I assume one dataset ist the mixture of two other datasets, but don't know exactly how to calculate this in gnuplot. Practically, I want to "fit" dataset3 by dataset2 and dataset1 using a function like this:

```
output = a*(dataset1) + b*(dataset2)
```

to get `a` and `b`.

Comment: I can understand if you can't provide some code, but could you please provide some minimal example data? How does it look like? Do you want to deconvolute some spectra? Can dataset1 and dataset2 be approximated by a "simple" function, e.g. like Gaussian or Exponential or whatever function?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have some data like this:

```
1 1 6.95322
1 2 10.9421
1 3 14.9826
1 4 19.4772
2 1 10.03
2 2 13.8502
2 3 17.9662
2 4 21.9018
3 1 12.7868
3 2 16.8742
3 3 21.0967
3 4 24.3392
4 1 16.4094
4 2 20.2189
4 3 24.5766
4 4 27.1483
```

You can write your function "output=a*(dataset1)+b*(dataset2)" and fit it like this:

```
f(x,y) = a*x + b*y
fit f(x,y) "a.dat" using 1:2:3 via a,b
```

The result:

```
...
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = 3.02235          +/- 0.06193      (2.049%)
b               = 3.95873          +/- 0.06193      (1.564%)
...
```

I have generated the example data with `a=3` and `b=4`.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically identical with maij's solution, but with copy&paste&run code, including "x"-data, and illustration. Everytime, it creates some spectra with random noise. Just skip this part and replace `$Data` with your file. In case you have your datasets in different files you either have to copy them togther or play some tricks with gnuplot. Make sure that the "x"-coordinate and step size is identical for all datasets, otherwise you would have to interpolate to have identical x-values.

**Code:**

```
### fit to find superposition factors
reset session

# generate some random test data
f1(x) = exp(-(x**2)/5) + rand(0)*0.05
f2(x) = exp(-((x-4)**2)/5) + rand(0)*0.05
a0 = int(rand(0)*10+5)
b0 = int(rand(0)*10+2)
f3(x) = a0*f1(x) + b0*f2(x) + rand(0)*0.05
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(f1(x)):(f2(x)):(f3(x)) w table
unset table

set fit quiet results
f(x,y) = a*x + b*y
fit f(x,y) $Data using 2:3:4 via a,b

plot \
    $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 ps 0.4 ti "Dataset 1", \
    '' u 1:3 w lp pt 7 ps 0.4 ti "Dataset 2", \
    '' u 1:4 w lp pt 7 ps 0.4 ti "Dataset 3", \
    '' u 1:(a*$2 + b*$3) w l lw 2 \
    ti sprintf("\n\n\nSuperposition\n D3 = a*D1 + b*D2\na: %g\nb: %g", a,b)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]